# GENERAL RELATIVITY: gravitational time dilation outside 2 bodies

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time-dilation, binary-stars

I know that gravitational time dilation near a single body is:

$$T_2=T_1\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}} $$

Can you give gravitational time dilation formula when in proximity to multiple bodies?

Comment: You're going to need to clarify this question.

Comment: In the weak field you can multiply the factors each of the bodies give at the respective distance to them, but in the strong field you need to do it numerically since there is no exact solution for that. If you keep the two masses at a fixed distance relative to each other you could use the [Kastor Traschen metric](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/32.html) but if the orbit each other dynamically that won't work.

Comment: @Yukterez if they orbit each other maintaining the proper distance fixed it should not be a problem, you can choose a co-rotating reference frame so that you treat them as fixed, if i remember correctly

Comment: You are highlighting the issue that, while in Newtonian gravity any system with more than 2 bodies has no general solution, in General Relativity it's even worse – no system with more than 1 body has a general solution.

Comment: A general solution doesn't exist either with 1 body to be honest. Schwartzschild or kerr it's not what i would call a general solution, due to high number of symmetries required they are far distant from being a general solution. In GR you can construct only classes of solutions with given symmetries, but a general solution to Einstein's equation do not exist. A good reference on the topic of solving GR is the book "Gravitational solitons - Belinski & Verdaguer"

Comment: In weak field limit the Newtonian potential gives you the factor. That also offers a useful rough approximation at intermediate fields.

Answer (score 2):

A general formula doesn't exist, you need to calculate it (or evaluate it numerically) yourself depending in the specific parameters of your system.
To evaluate it you first need to solve the Einstein equations and find the metric associated to your specific problem configuration.
Given that you can proceed to evaluate the time dilation ad you would do with a single Schwartzschild body but using the metric tensor you have just found.